How do I nicely structure MUI files while retaining functionality?
The Windows SDK's resource compiler (rc) lets you generate Multilingual User Interface (MUI) resource files by passing in an XML configuration file (documented here) which will generate two RES files with one RC file; one for the language-neutral resources, and one for the localized resources. This works fine when you're just toying around with it, but I've had trouble with integrating it into my own Visual C++ solution.
The resource compiler creates a special MUI resource in both files to facilitate easy retrieval of localized resources (e.g. loading a string from a handle to Application.exe will retrieve it from its MUI located at en-US\Application.exe.mui). However, this MUI resource contains a checksum (which can be checked with the muirct -d command) which must be the same between both files. I have tried putting the exact same resources, same IDs, same data, and everything in both my application and its MUI, and no matter what, they turn out having different checksums. For this reason, I believe the only way to get the checksums to match is to use one RC file for both language-neutral and localized resources. My question then is: is there a nice way to use one RC file and be able to produce one MUI file for each language I need to support? Or is there another way I can produce MUI files with matching checksums?

From my viewpoint, the checksum value can be copied and pasted. For example, this attribute allows you to copy the checksum from a single language-specific resource file, by convention the one for English (United States), and place the checksum in a different language-specific resource file.
